# Using CAPI engine with openssl

Tags: openssl, cryptoapi

To load the capi engine dynamically, the following code is used:

```
EVP_PKEY *key = NULL;
ENGINE_load_builtin_engines();
ENGINE *engine = ENGINE_by_id("dynamic");
ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(engine, "SO_PATH", "./capi.dll", 0); 
ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(engine, "LOAD", NULL, 0); 
ENGINE_init(engine);
```

While debugging I checked, `ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(engine, "LOAD", NULL, 0)` is failing. So what could be the reason for this?

I have not build openssl for using `capi`, I am using default `capi.dll` that came with openssl.
Should I build the openssl again with capi enabled in openssl.cfg file, or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does [`ERR_get_error`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_get_error.html) return?

Answer (score 1):

I had basically the same issue using `capi.dll` on the command line:

```
openssl engine dynamic -t -pre SO_PATH:./capi.dll -pre LOAD -post list_csps
```

After lot of trial and error, I found that the DLL I was using was a dummy! It basically contained a bind_engine function that always returned 0 (which means failure). Using a CAPI DLL that was natively compiled under Windows it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I spent time trying to find the capi.dll only to realize it was already compiled into the Windows openssl components.

From the command line:

```
openssl engine capi
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (pretty obscure) reason why engine loading may fail is that the library itself requires another library, which is not found. In this case, one simply gets the generic `No such file or directory` error (although the path of the library, e.g., `./capi.dll`, is correct).

To check if this is the problem, try

```
ldd ./capi.dll
```

or

```
cygcheck ./capi.dll
```

and if so, copy the missing library dependencies (e.g., `libeay32.dll`) to the current directory.